# Unable to build Spark application with multiple main classes for Databricks job

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-workflows

I have a spark application that contains multiple spark jobs to be run on Azure data bricks. I want to build and package the application into a fat jar. The application is able to compile successfully. While I am trying to package (command: sbt package) the application, it gives an error  ***"[warn] multiple main classes detected: run 'show discoveredMainClasses' to see the list".***

How to build the application jar (Without specifying any main class) so that I can upload it to Databricks job and specify the main classpath over there?

Comment: Try this parameter and give the main classpath which you want to run: --className={main class path}

Answer (score 1):

This message is just a warning (see `[warn]` in it), it doesn't prevent generation of the jar files (normal or fat). Then you can upload resulting jar to DBFS (or ADLS for newer Databricks Runtime versions), and create [Databricks job](https://docs.databricks.com/jobs.html) either as Jar task, or Spark Submit task.

If `sbt` fails, and doesn't produce jars, then you have some plugin that forces error on the warnings.

Also notice that `sbt package` doesn't produce fat jar - it produce jar only for classes in your project.  You will need to use `sbt assembly` (install [sbt-assembly plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) for that) to generate fat jar, but make sure that you marked Spark & Delta dependencies as `provided`.